# Changing individual symbol

Tags: symbology

How can I change an individual symbol on my map without changing all the other symbols? I can't click on an specific point to specify the picture.

Comment: Could you update your question with what software and versin you are working with? A screen shot of your situation might help bring clarity as well. Use the Edit button below your question.

Answer (score 0):

If it's shapefiles we are talking about:

1) Select the feature, 2) export it into a seperate file. 3) Change symbol.